# Debian apt and ipv6

Tags: linux, networking, apt, ipv6

I have an ipv6-only Server and want to update the system. But if I execute `apt update` I get the following message:

```
Fehl:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  »deb.debian.org« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden.
Fehl:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
  »deb.debian.org« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden.
Fehl:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
  »security.debian.org« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden.
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Alle Pakete sind aktuell.
W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease »deb.debian.org« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden.
W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease »security.debian.org« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden.
W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease »deb.debian.org« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden.
W: Einige Indexdateien konnten nicht heruntergeladen werden. Sie wurden ignoriert oder alte an ihrer Stelle benutzt.
```

The message means "could not resolve the deb.debian.org addresses. But if I try it with the `host` or `nslookup` command, everything is fine. If I insert the debian ipv6 address in `/etc/hosts`, then I can `ping` it and apt is working fine.

My `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]
networks:       files dns

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

My resolv.conf (the nameserver is my local gateway)

```
search fritz.box
nameserver fe80::3631:c4ff:fe01:7a9d
```

The command `apt -o Acquire::ForceIPv6=true update` does NOT work.

What should I do to get it working without changing the `/etc/hosts` file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I resolved it for myself, after adding my resolv.conf to this post :D
Since the Nameserver was the "LINK LOCAL" address of my router i realized that i needed the GLOBAL Address to work for external addresses (at least with ipv6).
So i checked it with "ip neigh", added it, and it worked! :)

Comment: I think your reasoning is incorrect but your solution is right. Link local addresses can't be used on their own. You must specify which interface they are for. Eg fe80::1 might need to be specified as fe80::1%eth0

Comment: So i had to specify the Nameserver in the resolv.conf with fe80:xx:yy:zz%eth0  ?

Comment: yes if eth0 is your internet connection. It's worth noting that not everything properly supports this syntax. Though I would hope glibc should. It also adds a limit: usury if you connect both Ethernet and WiFi, name servers could be accessed through any link. This is explicitly forcing it to use only eth0 (Ethernet?)

Comment: This syntax is strongly suggested by RFC (where the zone_id doesn't have to be an interface, but usually is  the interface name or interface index on many OS): https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4007#section-11